# How to express mysql_num_rows for a DB2 database in php

Tags: php, db2

So I have a query that works with a DB2 database just fine as a part of my code.

Let's say it's something really simple like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Mytable";
```

How can I express the `mysql_num_rows` PHP function to work with a DB2 database ad not MySQL?

```
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a corresponding [db2_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-num-rows.php) function if you enable the db2 extension for php.

Comment: thank you. it was so simple I feel stupid for asking the question. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just check this php page : [db2_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-num-rows.php)
It should be something like:

```
$numrows = db2_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: thank you. it was so simple I feel stupid for asking the question. thanks